# How can I check for a thumbnail in WordPress?

Tags: wp-query, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

How can I can I check if a post has a thumbnail and if does do something? If doesn't do something else. This is what I have:

```
 <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) ?>

 <?php the_thumbnail(); ?>
 ?>

 <?php else ?>

 <?php the_permalink();?>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Any help will be appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `the_post_thumbnail` instead of `the_thumbnail` within the loop. This is how it should be formatted:

```
<?php if(have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_post();
        if(has_post_thumbnail()){
            the_post_thumbnail();
        }
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new to WP, would this go inside the <?php if (have_posts()) : ?> loop???

Comment: You are correct! The loop populates these functions with the current postdata. :)

Comment: Would this give me any results '<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post()?> 
  <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {

    the_post_thumbnail(); 
    }
    ?>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>'

Comment: Instead of using all the <?php tags see my edited example.